# Doubt in prepositions

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

> "Sailing to the tune of our fate"

- The 'to' doesn't sound right, what might be its replacement?
- Can any other world replace the word *tune* in the sentence?

Comment: What is your phrase supposed to mean? What is *tune of our fate*?

Comment: The rhythm, maybe. Meaning, we are sailing through this life, as it's destined to be. Moving according to its tune. @Peter

Comment: The "to" is OK. For example "marching *to* the beat of a different drum". You could use "tune" or "rhythm" or another synonym. It depends on what feeling you are trying to convey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sailing **to** the tune of our fate.

has the feeling the tune is *driving*/*pushing* the sailing, as in

> Dancing **to** the EDM beat.
>
> Sailing **with** the tune of our fate.
>   Sailing **by** the tune of our fate.

both of these pose the tune as an accompaniment for the sailing.

> Sailing **from** the tune of our fate.

might have the meaning that one's fate was avoided and escaped.